# Android studio: kvm is required to run this AVD on linux mint

Tags: android-studio-3.0, kvm

I have already installed `qemu-kvm` on my device and also give a current user & root user permission on `kvm` group.

When I open AVD manager and launch `AVD in emulator` it works!!

But when I run my android project it still shows the error.

[**ERROR 1**]
[image: Android Studio]

and also when I choose `connected device` than it also shows an error:

[**ERROR 2**]

`Session 'app':Error installing apk` whereas I did `checked:usb debugging` in my phone and `unchecked:Enable instant run` in android studio setting.

SO how can I solve this problem ?

Any Help is appriciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Running this command should do it:

`sudo adduser $(whoami) kvm`

It adds your currently logged-in user to the `kvm` group. You'll need to logout and log back in for it to take effect